# Point Domain Names With keyword to main website?

Tags: seo, domains, robots.txt, local-seo

This is Question has been asked several time on Stack Exchange. I have read all those answer, still there are certain some technical specification answered. After lot of research on Internet , I simply found out that pointing many domains name(which contains keywords is not a good practice).

My question is - I have domain name `keyword1.com` , `Keyword2.com` , `Keyword3.com`. For each domain names I have also bought extensions like .org, .net , .info. And I have the final domain name i.e `final.com`.

What I am thinking is, I will restrict all domain with extension .org, .net , .info from showing in Google search using `Robot.txt`. If someone will open directly `keyword1.org` directly than using 301 redirect It will take the user to the `final.com`.

And For domains like `Keyword1.com` , `Keyword2.com` , `Keyword3.com` , I am thinking of uploading a article and few photos and **`Buy Now/See Product`** button on each website. If a user will click on the **`Buy now/See Products`** button , It will take user to the `final.com` website using `<a href>`.

Is this a good practice for search engine optimization? Does this approach contains any SEO risk? More one important thing I will have to buy these domain even if I don't use it because of the competition. Because Competition can buy those domain and use it. Therefore I have to block them.

Comment: No. Not this is not good. These are considered junk domains and will cause harm to your one domain. Do not engage in trickery. It will get you into trouble.

Comment: I will have to buy these domain even if I don't use it because of the competition. Because Competition can buy those domain and use it. Therefore I have to block them. Can you please point out the technicalities of this approach.

Comment: No you don't. Keyword domains do nothing for you. Creating thin content and just a few pages do nothing for you. Link schemes and redirects do nothing for you. Well... they do one thing, they get you penalized. Just build one good site that competes well and be done with it. Trickery will get you into serious trouble that you will not get out of easily and can take years.

Comment: Only Thing I should do is purchase and block them using robot.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice and solution if you want to buy all those domains is to block them if you are afraid that someone other can buy them.

But definitley don't use any redirection, it's not a good practice for SEO, and that approach contains very large scale of SEO risks.